# Javascript image gallery preventing the default

Tags: javascript, html

Hi i have a question regarding the image gallery i am trying to create. I have created a thumbnail viewer so when clicked the javascript then displays the thumbnail as a larger image on the same page, but i am required to add a way to still see the larger images when javascript is turned off. Here is my code 
(javascript)

```
    function changeImage(el)
{
    evt.preventDefault(evt);
    var elem = document.getElementById("slide");
    elem.src = "Assets/images/big/"+el+".jpg";
}
```

(HTML)

```
     <div id="gallery">
    <img id="slide" src="Assets/images/big/0.jpg" onClick="next();">
</div>
    <div id="thumb">

        <ul class="thumbnail">

            <li><a href="Assets/images/big/0.jpg" onClick="changeImage('0');"><img id="thumb" src="Assets/images/thumbs/0.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="Assets/images/big/1.jpg" onClick="changeImage('1');"><img id="thumb" src="Assets/images/thumbs/1.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="Assets/images/big/2.jpg" onClick="changeImage('2');"><img id="thumb" src="Assets/images/thumbs/2.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="Assets/images/big/3.jpg" onClick="changeImage('3');"><img id="thumb" src="Assets/images/thumbs/3.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="Assets/images/big/4.jpg" onClick="changeImage('4');"><img id="thumb" src="Assets/images/thumbs/4.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="Assets/images/big/5.jpg" onClick="changeImage('5');"><img id="thumb" src="Assets/images/thumbs/5.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="Assets/images/big/6.jpg" onClick="changeImage('6');"><img id="thumb" src="Assets/images/thumbs/6.jpg" /></a></li>
            <li><a href="Assets/images/big/7.jpg" onClick="changeImage('7');"><img id="thumb" src="Assets/images/thumbs/7.jpg" /></a></li>

        </ul>
    </div><!-- thumb-->
```

Now i had it so the thumbnail viewer was working but after adding the javascript fail option it no longer displays the image in the gallery but instead on a separate page as it would if there was no javascript, what would be the easiest way to fix this so when the javascript is working the thumbnail image is shown in the gallery when it is not it goes into a seperate page? Any help is much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

The `evt` variable is not declared anywhere. You would need to pass the event object into the function. Alternatively, you could put `return false` at the end of your `onclick` attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Remove

```
evt.preventDefault(evt);
```

and change

```
<a href="Assets/images/big/i.jpg" onClick="changeImage('i');"><img id="thumb" src="Assets/images/thumbs/i.jpg" /></a>
```

(i from 0 to 7) in your HTML codes to

```
<img class="thumb" src="Assets/images/thumbs/i.jpg" onclick="changeImage('i');" style="cursor:pointer;"/>
```

(`<a>` is removed, and `style` attribute is added to change the mouse cursor to `pointer`, and changed `id` to `class` - multiple elements having same ID is bad.)

Comment: Hi i tried to change this, hoping it was going to be an easy fix but no it didn't seem to change anything :(

Comment: hi thanks for your help, but how do i now add the option for when the javascript is switched off? All i need it to do is for it show the large image in a new window when it is clicked?

Comment: @LouisaGibbons Then follow Daniel Brockman's answer - change `function changeImage(el)` to `function changeImage(evt,el)` and change `onClick="changeImage('i');"` to `onclick="changeImage(event,'i');"`.

Answer (score 0):

Return `false` from the event handler:

```
function changeImage(el) {
    var elem = document.getElementById("slide");
    elem.src = "Assets/images/big/" + el + ".jpg";
    return false;
}
```

And in html add `return` statement too:

```
<ul class="thumbnail">

    <li><a href="Assets/images/big/0.jpg" onClick="return changeImage('0');"><img id="thumb" src="Assets/images/thumbs/0.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="Assets/images/big/1.jpg" onClick="return changeImage('1');"><img id="thumb" src="Assets/images/thumbs/1.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="Assets/images/big/2.jpg" onClick="return changeImage('2');"><img id="thumb" src="Assets/images/thumbs/2.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="Assets/images/big/3.jpg" onClick="return changeImage('3');"><img id="thumb" src="Assets/images/thumbs/3.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="Assets/images/big/4.jpg" onClick="return changeImage('4');"><img id="thumb" src="Assets/images/thumbs/4.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="Assets/images/big/5.jpg" onClick="return changeImage('5');"><img id="thumb" src="Assets/images/thumbs/5.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="Assets/images/big/6.jpg" onClick="return changeImage('6');"><img id="thumb" src="Assets/images/thumbs/6.jpg" /></a></li>
    <li><a href="Assets/images/big/7.jpg" onClick="return changeImage('7');"><img id="thumb" src="Assets/images/thumbs/7.jpg" /></a></li>

</ul>
```